# Node "req is not defined"

Tags: node.js

When I try to start following script:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}).listen(8000);

var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;

console.log(ip)
```

I get following Error:

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
ReferenceError: req is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/IPDeliverer/server.js:9:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:32)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:41)
```

My first guess was, that there is some module missing, so I installed the following module like this:

```
npm install req
```

and then I included following line

```
var req = require("./node_modules/req/node_modules/request");
```

but it is still not working. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Show the current source, what module you think you're using, etc. It's not clear why you'd be trying to get headers outside of any connection, though.

Comment: You probably mismatched the frameworks. Pure HTTP has request in handler specified in *createServer*. *req* is specific for the Express framework. So move your IP checking into that callback (keep in mind Node code is often async).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've named the Request `request`, not `req`, also every callback has it's own `request`, so checking the IP outside the callback like that doesn't make sense. Use `request` inside the callback instead:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();

  var ip = request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || request.connection.remoteAddress;

  console.log(ip)
}).listen(8000);
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable req is not defined there. You have to move it inside of a request handler. Try this:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  var ip = request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || request.connection.remoteAddress;

  console.log(ip)
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}).listen(8000);
```